# Can't remove table items: bad argument #2 to 'remove' (number expected, got Vector3)

Tags: lua, roblox

I just encountered this strange problem where I can add vector3 values to a table but not remove them. When I am using table.insert the second value says it needs to be a "number Pos". I put a vector3 value their. When I try to remove it using table.remove the second value says it needs to be a "number Pos" so I inserted another vector3 value but it throws an error.

I have already tried changing everything from vector3 values to CFrame values but neither of these work. I have also tried storing the position in a value and then trying to remove that from the table but this doesn't work either.

Only the table.remove part has a problem. I can't remove any vector3 value from the table.

```
  for i,p in pairs(ores:GetChildren()) do
    for _,v in ipairs(Airs) do
      if v==p.Position then
        table.remove(Airs,p.Position)
      end
     end
   end
```

Here is the complete error that roblox throws me when I run the code. It only happens when removing vector3 values from a table.

***ServerScriptService.GenerateBlock:73: bad argument #2 to 'remove' (number expected, got Vector3)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table.remove` receives an index, not a value. So try `table.remove(Airs,_)`.

Comment: Thank you! I never knew that it finds the index not the object.